# Can u please tell me if their is any difference between the codes. And if their is, Then what is the reason behind it?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, react-router

**1.**

```
import React from 'react'; import {Link} from 'react-router-dom';

function CardItem(props) {  return (        <>       <li className='cards__item'>
          <Link className='cards__items__link' to={props.path}>
           <figure className='cards__item__pic-wrap' data-category={props.label}>
            <img
            className='cards__items__img' 
            alt='Travel Image'
            src={props.src}             />
           </figure>
            <div className='cards__item__info'>
             <h5 className='cards__item__text'>{props.text}</h5>
            </div>   
          </Link>        </li>      </>         ); }

export default CardItem;
```

***It outputs as ------[the pages are enlargened and the images that are used as cards are itself too big that they do not appear on the page itself. they display themselves in an unorganized manner.[][1]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XOCAr.jpg)***

**2.**

```
import React from 'react'; import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

function CardItem(props) {   return (
    <>
      <li className='cards__item'>
        <Link className='cards__item__link' to={props.path}>
          <figure className='cards__item__pic-wrap' data-category={props.label}>
            <img
              className='cards__item__img'
              alt='Travel Image'
              src={props.src}
            />
          </figure>
          <div className='cards__item__info'>
            <h5 className='cards__item__text'>{props.text}</h5>
          </div>
        </Link>
      </li>
    </>   ); }

export default CardItem;
```

***It outputs as desired[In this the images display themselves correctly and inline as desired and styled](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fUX84.jpg)***

Comment: plz, ignore the formatting of lines as it is the same for both!

Comment: What are we supposed to be comparing? Hard to know what styles are that apply to the classes that would make things render differently. Also unclear why you would use a fragment and not just return the li.

Comment: So you need community support for diff'ing files?

Comment: I am a new learner in react and practicing on my own, I coded myself but got errors and tried debugging them but wasn't able to do so, hence posted the question to the community.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Code one has `className='cards__items__img'`, code two has `className='cards__item__img'`.

Code one has `className='cards__items__link'`, code two has `className='cards__item__link'`.

Items is plural on first code and singular on second. Reason? I don't know but the first code is very poorly formatted.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I wasn't able to get it.